# How to always append attributes to Laravel Eloquent model?

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, restful-architecture

I was wondering how to always append some data to Eloquent model without the need of asking for it for example when getting Posts form database I want to append the user info for each user as:

```
{
    id: 1
    title: "My Post Title"
    body: "Some text"
    created_at: "2-28-2016"
    user:{
            id: 1,
            name: "john smith",
            email: "example@mail.com"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

After some search I found that you simply need to add the attribute you wants to the `$appends` array in your Eloquent Model:

```
 protected $appends = ['user'];
```

> **Update:** If the attribute exists in the database you can just use `protected $with= ['user'];` according to  [David Barker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010632/david-barker) comment below

Then create an Accessor as:

```
public function getUserAttribute()
{

    return $this->user();

}
```

This way you always will have the user object for each post available as:

```
{
    id: 1
    title: "My Post Title"
    body: "Some text"
    created_at: "2-28-2016"
    user:{
            id: 1,
            name: "john smith",
            email: "example@mail.com"
         }
}
```

Comment: Your use case is a bit wierd as a relationship with `User` would make `$model->user` available to you without needing to use appends. Also when the model is converted to JSON or cast to array, the `user` key would exist if you had loaded in that relationship. If you always want the user add `protected $with = ['user'];` to the model.

Comment: yes that right with your way I always have to use `$model->user` but what I needed to have the user object without manually asking for it in addition I don't wanna go through a loop and I'm using it in an API so I can't get those when I'm displaying a  list of articles. this way the user object will always automatically be available to you.

Comment: No, not when you add `protected $with = ['user']` it will be loaded automatically for you when you get the model. Appends is for when you want data that is not available in the database on your model.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know about that. I will check it out and update my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a package to automatically append accessors to response https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-auto-append

Comment: Nice but how remove $appends from result?

Answer (score 13):

I found this concept is interesting, I learn and share things.
Here in this example, I append id_hash variable which then converted into method by this logic.

It takes first char and converts into upper case i.e. `Id` and letter after underscore to uppercase i.e. `Hash`.

Laravel itself add **get** and **Attribute** to combine all together it gives  `getIdHashAttribute()`

```
class ProductDetail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['product_id','attributes','discount','stock','price','images'];
    protected $appends = ['id_hash'];


    public function productInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product','id','product_id');
    }

    public function getIdHashAttribute(){
        return Crypt::encrypt($this->product_id);
    }
}
```

To simplify things append variable would be like this

```
protected $appends = ['id_hash','test_var'];
```

The method would be defined in the model like this

```
 public function getTestVarAttribute(){
        return "Hello world!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example in the model:

```php
protected $appends = [
    'mobile_with_code',
];

public function getFormattedMobileAttribute() {
    if (!$this->calling_code) {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    return $this->calling_code . '-' . $this->mobile;
}
```

You can use it with the object normally.

In view:

```php
{{mobile_with_code}}
```

Comment: You're appending `mobile_with_code` but your function is not named `getMobileWithCode`.  I think you'd either need to rename your append or your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table is incorrect, you dont need to append anything it can be loaded using relationships:

first your post table should have user_id column which refer to your user table id column:
{
id: 1
user_id: 1
title: "My Post Title"
body: "Some text"
created_at: "2-28-2016"
}

then in your post model you to have to define relationship based on your user_id:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\User", "user_id");
}
```

then in your get api call all you have to do is load this relationship using:
e.g. Posts::with("user")->get();